# Unresponsive touch in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, highcharts

I need to display four realtime smooth graphs representing user's biodata in my android application. I tried every free android library but they were not as smooth as their javascript counterparts. So I decided to use the highcharts js in webview.

Four graphs in the same screen works smoothly. But webview is not recognising touch events quickly. I tried playing with H/w accelartion, touch events etc. but it did not help.

Whenever I touch a button on the webview logcat says :-

```
"12-13 16:13:37.436: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(9308): blockWebkitDraw"
"12-13 16:13:37.441: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(9308): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse"
```

After touching buttons multiple times it says :-

```
"12-13 16:13:37.806: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(9308): blockWebkitDraw lockedtrue"
```

So basically any touch on highcharts graph or the buttons does not work quickly. I am loading html/js/css from assets folder.

What fixes I need to perform in webview to resolve this? I don't think there is any problem with my html/js/css code because it runs perfectly fine on Chrome mobile.

Comment: Have you tried to use phonegap?

Comment: Most of my application is already developed using Android Java SDK, so switching to phonegap is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Having your app an important delay is a possible indicator that probably you're doing some hard work in the UIThread that you should probably sepparate in a Thread or an AsyncTask.

You don't mention what is supposed to happen when you touch a chart, but some code would probably clarify that.

I strongly recommend installing Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool (assuming you use Eclipse, otherwise you should find a similar tool for the environment you use) and combine it's usage with DDMS. This will give you some clues of where the bottleneck might be.

This is a good tutorial on how to use them: http://therockncoder.blogspot.com.es/2012/09/fixing-android-memory-leak.html

This one's very clarifying too: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/01/21/10-tips-for-using-the-eclipse-memory-analyzer/